# Library installed but can't be imported

Tags: python, installation, import, pip, pysimplegui

I have already installed "PySimpleGUI" library, but I can't import it. In my terminal window I typed:

```
pip install PySimpleGUI
```

And it worked, because I typed it again and received this message:

```
PS C:\Users\raulc\AMBIENTES> pip install PySimpleGUI 
Requirement already satisfied: PySimpleGUI in c:\users\raulc\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (4.59.0)
```

However, I can't import it, that's what i get:

`Import "PySimpleGUI" could not be resolved`

Comment: are you located in the correct environment when executing your python script in the terminal window ? You can see that by the parentheses at the beginning of the prompt line.

Comment: Hi, give a look here https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/5189